# Do python subclasses have to necessarily call their superclass constructor?

Tags: python

I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
class myclass1(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1):            
        self.var1 = arg1         

class myclass2(myclass1):
    def f1(self):
        print "in f1"            

class myclass3(myclass1):
    def __init__(self, arg1):        
        self.var2 = arg1            
        self.c2 = myclass2()

p= myclass3(5)
```

This gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./pythoninherit.py", line 39, in <module>
p= myclass3(5)
File "./pythoninherit.py", line 29, in __init__
self.c2 = myclass2()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Question:
Why is the error given?

Why was the myclass1 `__init__` called automatically in this case?

I was under the impression that this does not happen in python.

Comment: The `__init__` method is inherited. The `__init__` method in `class1` takes an argument and you're calling it without arguments.

Comment: because you didn't call `__init__` with enough arguments. So to answer your title "Yes".  When you construct your subclass you need to pass the argument that would be passed to the parent class.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Please add this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__init__` method in `myclass1` is inherited by `myclass2`. When you instantiate `myclass2`, you're calling the `__init__` method from `myclass1`, but it takes an argument and you're not passing it.

Answer (score 2):

They don't always have to, but they have to override the base `__init__` if they're going to change how initialization works.  If the base class requires an argument to initialize, and the subclass doesn't, then the subclass is changing the API and needs to write its own `__init__`.  (Whether it calls the base class depends on whether it wants to inherit the base init behavior.)

In your example, `myclass2` inherits the `__init__` from myclass1, but you don't pass an argument when you do `myclass2()`, so it doesn't work.  If you want to be able to instantiate `myclass2` without passing an argument, you need to write its `__init__` to allow that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that myclass2 is a subclass on myclass1 and you aren't passing arg1 to myclass2 on

```
self.c2 = myclass2()
```

needs to be

```
self.c2 = myclass2(arg1)
```

So the myclass2 is calling myclass1's `__init__` which is expecting one argument

Answer (score 0):

like you gave 5 as a parameter for `myclass3`, you must give something for `myclass2` inside `myclass3`, like:

```
class myclass3(myclass1):
    def __init__(self, arg1):        
        self.var2 = arg1            
        self.c2 = myclass2(5)
```